# How to SSH to over 2000 nodes?

Tags: linux, ssh, kernel, python, tcp

The first thing we're going to do is get simple information from over 2,000 servers with ssh, but I want this to be over in 30 seconds.

The use of GNU Parallel and Python paramiko+multiprocessing

Both have a randomized bottleneck, slowing down. Can you solve this problem? Doneed kernel tuning? The OS used is CentOS 7 (Core 24)

add python code

```
        ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(host,username=username,password=password)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
        outlines=stdout.readlines()
        resp=''.join(outlines)
        print(resp)
        stdin.close()
        ssh.close()

    except Exception as err:
 
        print(err)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    host = subprocess.check_output("echo 10.0.{{1..26},{51..146}}.{1..100}", shell="True", universal_newlines=True)
    list = host.strip().split(" ")
    print (list)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    pool.map(loadavg, list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("time :", time.time() - start)
```

Comment: 2000 servers in 30 seconds is 66.6667 connections per second. Over 24 cores, that's ~2.7 ssh connections per core per second.   Even over a 10GB or 100GB switch, that's unlikely to complete in under 30 secs...ssh just has too much overhead, as does tcp.  I suggest you look in to [snmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) rather than re-invent the wheel - there are good reasons why snmp uses udp rather than tcp.   udp has its problems too, but it is fast.  And remember to use firewall rules to restrict access only to authorised hosts.

Comment: 1. overloading `list` is a terrible idea in python and you should not do it. Use **any** other name. 2. Instead of using a shell expansion, your list of hosts could be trivially generated in python itself.

Comment: @MarcusMüller how to generated hosts in python? Is it as easy and simple as echo? so I changed list name

Comment: `hosts = [f"10.0.{x:d}.{y:d}" for x in range(1, 27) for y in range(1, 101)] + [f"10.0.{x:d}.{y:d}" for x in range(51, 147) for y in range(1, 101)]`

Answer (score 3):

**Ansible** is pretty much meant for this kind of task: administrating / exchanging data with thousands of servers.

Ansible has *playbooks*, which list the commands to be executed for each host. With *strategies* [you can set](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#playbooks-strategies) whether all hosts are worked on one after the other, or whether hosts are contacted simultaneously.

If this still doesn't allow for your 30s window, you can easily combine with Paul's "tree" approach: Ansible supports [delegation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) *exactly* for this use case.

Ansible would also save you from writing python. It has an easy syntax for specifying ranges of hosts to connect to.

Comment: I've been using ansibles as you say, but it's too slow

Comment: including the delegation and the parallel execution strategy?

Comment: If that's the case, your connection establishing simply takes too long, and that means it's a two-sided problem: all your servers need to be very fast as well, not only the controlling machine(s).

Answer (score 2):

I can do 4000 hosts in 20 seconds and 2000 hosts in 10 seconds with:

```
killall ssh-agent
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3=30000
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2=20000
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1=10000

cat hosts |
  time parallel --lb --roundrobin --pipe -I dummy -N 50 parallel --timeout 4 --retries 10 -j50 --tag ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@{} echo {}
```

The `gc_thresh` is needed because otherwise your arp table will overflow. This will cause `ssh` to get stuck.

If you have a lot of `arp -n | grep incomplete`, try:

```
parallel 'echo 3600000 >' ::: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/*/base_reachable_time_ms
```

Be aware that this causes arp entries to hang around for 1 hour before they are refreshed.

*Edit*

I can reproduce the timeouts if:

- Hosts are directly connected to the same LAN
- The arp cache is not warmed up
- There are alot of parallel tasks

Comment: i just try but Timeout occurs in over 1000

Comment: I found the arp table problem in `dmesg`. Does `dmesg` give you any indication?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a multi-drop method.

At two levels, have your initial instance contact 40 servers, each of which contacts 50 others and relays back the results: each level needs to complete in 15 seconds. The initial request lists the nodes for which each secondary node is responsible.

If you can deal with three levels, the fan-out numbers come down to 13 x 13 x 13, and they get 10 seconds each, which sounds feasible.