# Parallel SSH to 500 docker containers stalls: ksoftirqd to blame?

Tags: ssh, linux-kernel, docker, arp

Answering
[How to SSH to over 2000 nodes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687973/how-to-ssh-to-over-2000-nodes/688273#688273) I discovered the following:

Running 500 parallel `ssh` to 500 servers is no problem if either:

- the servers are not on the same LAN (i.e. they are routed through different routers).
- the servers are Docker containers on the same machine (localhost).
- a job is started no faster than 1 every 30 ms.

So these all work:

```
head -n 500 ext.ipaddr | parallel -j 500 ssh {} uptime
head -n 500 localhost.docker.ipaddr | parallel -j 500 ssh {} uptime
head -n 500 local.lan.docker.ipaddr | parallel --delay 0.03 -j 500 ssh {} uptime
```

What I do not understand is why this does not work:

```
head -n 500 local.lan.docker.ipaddr | parallel -j 500 ssh {} uptime
```

I.e. `ssh` to 500 Docker containers on a server on the local LAN with no delay (the problem can sometimes be seen with as low as 5 Docker containers).

When I do that, I get a lot of "No route to host".

I come to the conclusion it has to do with arp.

In the working cases I get something like:

```
06:15:06.605997 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.113 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.617110 ARP, Reply 172.24.0.113 is-at 02:42:ac:18:00:71, length 46
06:15:06.636660 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.115 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.648457 ARP, Reply 172.24.0.115 is-at 02:42:ac:18:00:73, length 46
06:15:06.660832 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.116 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.672328 ARP, Reply 172.22.0.116 is-at 02:42:ac:16:00:74, length 46
06:15:06.692116 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.117 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.703215 ARP, Reply 172.21.0.117 is-at 02:42:ac:15:00:75, length 46
06:15:06.717891 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.117 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.729403 ARP, Reply 172.23.0.117 is-at 02:42:ac:17:00:75, length 46
06:15:06.752089 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.114 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.764744 ARP, Reply 172.24.0.114 is-at 02:42:ac:18:00:72, length 46
06:15:06.783677 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.116 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.795258 ARP, Reply 172.24.0.116 is-at 02:42:ac:18:00:74, length 46
06:15:06.809392 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.118 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.820770 ARP, Reply 172.23.0.118 is-at 02:42:ac:17:00:76, length 46
06:15:06.842422 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.118 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.853491 ARP, Reply 172.21.0.118 is-at 02:42:ac:15:00:76, length 46
06:15:06.871436 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.117 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.882957 ARP, Reply 172.22.0.117 is-at 02:42:ac:16:00:75, length 46
06:15:06.902872 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.120 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.913643 ARP, Reply 172.23.0.120 is-at 02:42:ac:17:00:78, length 46
06:15:06.932819 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.119 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:15:06.944045 ARP, Reply 172.21.0.119 is-at 02:42:ac:15:00:77, length 46
```

So a request followed immediately by a reply.

In the failing case I get:

```
06:17:35.764287 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.169 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.768654 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.169 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.771642 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.169 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.772369 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.109 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.772384 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.110 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.772387 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.111 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.772388 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.109 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.772395 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.107 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.776378 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.108 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.776398 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.108 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.776401 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.106 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.776408 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.109 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.777417 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.170 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.783320 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.170 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.789594 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.171 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.792286 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.171 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.798649 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.171 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.803277 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.173 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.804366 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.112 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.804383 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.113 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.804385 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.110 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.804387 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.112 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.804388 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.112 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.804389 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.114 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.804390 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.111 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.804391 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.109 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.804393 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.108 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.806772 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.170 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.811874 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.172 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.816238 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.172 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.820150 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.174 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.826595 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.175 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.832707 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.173 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.835588 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.176 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.836369 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.114 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.836384 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.112 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.836392 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.113 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.840372 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.115 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.840394 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.110 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.840397 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.111 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.840400 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.111 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.840408 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.113 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.842467 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.172 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.844844 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.173 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.853446 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.174 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.855394 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.173 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.860520 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.178 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.865012 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.175 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.868369 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.116 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.868391 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.116 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.868394 ARP, Request who-has 172.22.0.115 tell 172.22.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.868395 ARP, Request who-has 172.21.0.117 tell 172.21.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.868397 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.113 tell 172.24.254.254, length 28
06:17:35.868398 ARP, Request who-has 172.23.0.115 tell 172.23.254.254, length 28
```

So loads of requests, but no answers. This explains the "No route to host". But it raises a new question: Why are there no replies?

`dmesg` and syslog of the container server does not show anything when running the above: No "server is under arp flooding attack, stopping answering arp requests" or similar.

The LAN is 1 Gbit/s and there is no other traffic. The traffic occupies in the order of 1 Mbit/s.

The container server is 90% idle, but `top` shows `ksoftirqd` maxing out a few cores:

```
top - 06:38:38 up  6:33,  4 users,  load average: 3.94, 5.16, 4.34
Tasks: 17106 total,   7 running, 17098 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  1.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  6.4 si,  0.0 st
GiB Mem :    503.9 total,    162.4 free,    303.6 used,     37.9 buff/cache
GiB Swap:    200.0 total,    200.0 free,      0.0 used.    199.6 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND            
     25 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 100.0   0.0  24:13.88 ksoftirqd/2        
     31 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 100.0   0.0   1:39.16 ksoftirqd/3        
     37 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  99.8   0.0  14:31.28 ksoftirqd/4        
     49 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  99.8   0.0  22:29.80 ksoftirqd/6        
   2899 root      20   0   20.5g   1.3g  51704 S  29.2   0.3 171:22.30 dockerd            
3230170 root      20   0   29912  23504   3428 R  25.7   0.0   0:39.58 top                
     37 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 100.0   0.0  14:23.61 ksoftirqd/4
```

This maxing out happens exactly when running the `ssh`s with no delay. With 30 ms delay the cores are not maxed out, but run at 30%.

So maybe the explanation is that `ksoftirqd` starts serving a arp request, but is interrupted with a new request before it completes answering the request. In that case it looks like bad design: It could be used to DoS the containers. It would be better if it simply ignored new arp requests while processing an arp request.

Is this the explanation? Or is there a different reason? Is there a workaround (apart from putting in a delay)?

Server and client both run Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Are the docker containers on different containers in the LAN, and does it matter how many machines they are spread across? (I realise that not many people here will have a LAN with 500 machines to spread the containers fully). I realise that you want this to be fast, but does it make a difference if you lower the number of parallel connection attempts?

Comment: Not an answer, but there is a program for doing parallel ssh. It will solve many problems.  Including collecting error messages. Sorry, I can't remember the name.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: You don't know who you're talking to, right? @OleTange is the author of Gnu parallel, so I guess he'll not start using an alternative to `parallel ssh {}`, I also doubt that whatever program you're thiking about (I know a few, I guess @OleTange knows more - based on the "know your competition"-paradigm) does any different in this situation.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity "know your competition" — Life is not a zero-sum game. Cooperation is a better strategy.